# codeIgniter 404 not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my local computer I am using xampp and the codeigniter is running but after I moved the codeigniter application to server I get 404 error Not found.

```
The requested URL /app/index.php/Welcome was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny16 with Suhosin-Patch Server at XXXXXXXXX.com.au Port 81
```

I have tried changing config

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://XXXXXXXXX.com.au/';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

But it did not resolve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not pretty sure about that as the codeigniter minimum is 5.1 http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/requirements.html

Comment: Did you run PHP files in your server previously? I am in doubt of server configuration problems you may have.

Comment: You're going to need to give us more to go on. All of these answers are great answers, but we're shooting in the dark. What does the file structure look like, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here - the capital 'W'.

```
The requested URL /app/index.php/Welcome was not found on this server.
```

You moved from a Windows WAMP setup - to I bet a Linux Apache/PHP server.

Windows is not case sensitive. Linux IS case sensitive.

So make sure all your capitalization are correct. Change 'Welcome' to 'welcome'

**edit - to clarify it should be like this:**

**file name:** "welcome.php"  <- lowercase "w"

**class name:** class Welcome extends CI_Controller {}   <- Uppercase "W"

**to call the route:**  redirect ('welcome')   <- lowercase "w"

Comment: i still reckon its a case sensitive issue - its a common error. Have you tried to install a default codeingiter app on your server and check if that works?

Answer (score 0):

If you're application is installed in `/app`, then you need to update the base_url to be:

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://XXXXXXXXX.com.au/app/';
```

Answer (score 0):

The CodeIgniter docs say it's usually the best to leave base_url field empty, so it can determine the correct URL itself. Especially emphasized for CI2.

Comment: @KarmicDice and I actually couldn't find the exact page where it says that :)